# Can iterators be iterated only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Consider the following example:

```
def foo(iterator):
    return sum(iterator) / max(iterator)
```

Is it safe to reuse the same iterator twice?

Comment: It was indeed strange that nobody had answered this simple question. Well, next time I'll try to change my search terms.

Comment: You're title is confusing iterators and iterables, some iterables can be iterated over many times (like `lists`)

Comment: Hmm I see. Should I edit the title despite the question is marked as duplicate?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Your comment is confusing "your" and "you're".

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not safe. Iterators are not sequences. Here's what happens with that `foo()` function using a generator, which is itself an iterator:

```
>>> foo(x for x in range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

This is because the iterator is already at its end when after `sum()` finished its job, so `max()` is getting no additional items from it. In general, it is not possible to reset an iterator so that it can be cycled through again. In order for the `foo()` function to properly support iterators, it must be rewritten so that the iterator is cycled through only once, for example by saving the items from `iterator` into a temporary `tuple` or `list`:

```
def foo(iterator):
    iterable = list(iterator)
    return sum(iterable) / max(iterable)
```

or, if `iterator` yields a large number of items, by *carefully* handling it using a `for` loop:

```
def foo(iterator):
    # allows iterables like lists or tuples to be passed as arguments
    iterator = iter(iterator)

    try:
        max_ = next(iterator)
        sum_ = max_
    except StopIteration:
        # iterator yields no items, return some default value
        return 0.0

    for element in iterator:
        sum_ += element
        max_ = max(max_, element)

    return sum_ / max_
```

This will produce the proper result:

```
>>> foo(x for x in range(10))
5.0
```

Comment: Or use `itertools.tee` or convert it to a list to reuse.